# Should I always check args for a function in PHP?

Tags: php

Background disclosure:
I've been working on PHP project for some time now, but only recently started seriously looking up best practices, oop design patterns, new php version features and so on.

A lot of my code ends up looking like this:

```
public function($arg1 = 'default', $arg2 = false)
{
   if(!empty($arg2) && $arg1 != 'default) {
     // do something here
    }
}
```

Almost all of the proper OOP code I've seen in github and whatnot never checks for the presence or correct type of the arguments used.

My question is: Is it considered to be a good practice to ALWAYS have redundant checks on arguments or only in particular situations when Something Bad (tm) might happen.

For instance, after running an SQL query and fetching the results I ALWAYS do
 `if(!empty($results)) //go do stuff`

Should I do this? Am I being paranoid?

Comment: i would consider it poor practice to 'always' do anything

Comment: I always check, but im far from best practice ;p, it not hurt and will make handling errors much easier

Comment: A start of better practice would be _not_ to give defaults if you don't _want_ those defaults, so there's a nice E_NOTICE error when people are using that code wrong, which could even be logged to determine where errors happen after the fact. Don't hide those errors for me please... Validating the content of your arguments depends on a case by case basis, which usually has to do with how potentially destructive or disruptive a wrong value there would be. Having no results for an SQL query is not an error, but a valid result in my book for instance.

Comment: @Wrikken: having no result for the query might lead to an error in the view due to $array not containing anything. Shouldn't I cover this case in the model?

Comment: Depends on whether _your_ code is responsible for creating the view (in which case it most likely still isn't an error per se , but will require another path through creating that view, so the `if()` is then apt), or only responsible for returning processed query results to other code (in which case you shouldn't meddle with it). That would illustrate the point that it depends on a case by case basis. But the main thing I'd like to repeat is: do not _hide_ errors. I like my error log. If you want the _handle_ the error in some way, by all means, but `trigger_error()` at the very least then.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of using Exceptions to handle errors but try/catch seems like an inelegant way of writing code. And I haven't seen this being used either. So what do I do?

Comment: Well, as I said, case by case basis... I disagree about exceptions being inelegant, but that is a matter of taste and let's not debate that. Also, 90% of PHP code is utter crap, not seeing something often does not mean it's not good. For my part, take a good look at Michal Hatak's answer, and yes, case by case basis means no definitive one true answer for you alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to define upfront what the function is supposed to do and to do proper exception handling.

Example - if I'm writing an application, which makes use of a library of mine, then either the application should do some checking or the library should.

I generally choose to do proper checking in the application, so I can notify the user properly. This also takes away the burden of doing it in the library and making it more flexible for use.

But if you choose to do it this way, you should make sure to write all your libraries and applications in a similar way (hence "standard") otherwise it becomes confusing.

I think most things on github will be in the library approach and therefore expect you to do some stuff in the app.

Comment: I think the mention of proper exception handling is important.  Its all about how your app responds to these potential failures.

Comment: So in other words, keep the if, and add an else throw new exception?

Comment: @Carvefx there is a little more nuance to it.  A concept of letting things 'bubble up'.  I'd read some tutorials or look at source code from other projects on github.  Writing tests can be another good approach to figuring this out.  Basically try and break things in every way, does the app respond the way you want?

Answer (score 2):

with classes you can check args easier via typehint

```
public function doSomething(My\Super\Cl $cl, array $params){
...
}
```

sometimes you can check args via `func_num_args`

i agree is good practice, i mean, its called [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)